# Algorithmic big o order of growth code

Tags: algorithm, discrete-mathematics

I'm doing an online course and i'm stuck on this question. I know there are similar questions but they don't help me.

> What is the order of growth of the worst case running time of the
>   following code fragment as a function of N?

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i*i*i < N; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j*j*j < N; j++)
        for (int k = 0; k*k*k < N; k++)
            sum++;
```

I thought that the order would be n^3 but I don't think this is correct because the loops only go through a third of n each time. So would that make it nlogn?

Also

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++)
    for (int j = 1; j <= N; j++)
        for (int k = 1; k <= N; k = k*2)
            for (int h = 1; h <= k; h++)
                sum++;
```

I think this one would be n^4 because you have n * n * 0.5n * 0.5n

Comment: It is in linear, `O(n)`, time. I had the same question back in my CS day, but forgot the technical explanation behind it. The short version is your iterators increase very quickly (`i^3`, `j^3`, etc.) to offset the thrice-nested loop. Making a plot in Excel really shows that it's linear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loops in fact only go up to the cube root of N. (i^3 < n, etc.)

The 3 nested loops of this length, give O(cube root of N, cubed). This O(N)

Of note, if you were correct and they each went to one third of N, then cubing this still gives O(N^3/9), 1/9 is constant, so this is O(n^3)

Comment: Can I also ask what you suggestion for this would be:

`int sum = 0;`
`for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++)`
`for (int j = 1; j <= N; j++)`
 `for (int k = 1; k <= N; k = k*2)`
 `for (int h = 1; h <= k; h++)`
 `sum++;`

I think this one would be n^4 because you have n * n * 0.5n * 0.5n

Comment: in `for (int k = 1; k <= N; k = k*2)` you are doubling k each time. If N is 1024, how many times do you execute that?

Comment: Well you'd execute for half of n so 516 times which would be 0.5?

Comment: No. start at one, then repeatedly double the value you have, tell me (or really, tell yourself, I already know) what sequence you generate.

Comment: It only executes 10 times because it doubles each time, so it's like 2^n. How does that contribute to the overall complexity?

Comment: That's the base 2 logarithm of n.

Comment: Thankyou. Can i ask what you would say the complexity of this one is? @moreON

Comment: You can ask, but I can't guarantee that you'll learn anything if I just tell you that it's O(n^3). The logn does disappear somewhere, I'll let you work out why.

Comment: I would think it's todo with the 4th inner loop and that meaning that for each element iterated through in the 3rd loop you have to iterate through all previous loops which would nullify the effect of the log(n) turning it into a o(n) operation

Comment: That's not mathematically precise, so I'm inclined to doubt your understanding.

Answer (score 1):

If you examine the value of `sum` for various values of `N`, then it becomes pretty clear what the time complexity of the algorithm is:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  for( int N=1 ; N<=100 ; ++N ) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i*i*i < N; i++)
      for (int j = 0; j*j*j < N; j++)
        for (int k = 0; k*k*k < N; k++)
          sum++;
    std::cout << "For N=" << N << ", sum=" << sum << '\n';
  }
  return 0;
}
```

You can then draw your own conclusions with greater insight.